# How can I query one object from a list without getting a collection?

Tags: c#

```
public static Treatment Find(int id, List<Treatment> treatments)
{
    var treatment = from t in treatments
                    where t.ID == id
                    select new Treatment(t.ID, t.Name);

    return treatment;
}
```

In the above example, I am attempting to pick one object out of a list of ~20 objects. What is the syntax (if one exists) to return only one object from that query, rather than a collection containing only one object?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `FirstOrDefault`

```
return treatment.FirstOrDefault();
```

It returns the first object in the sequence otherwise it returns the default value for the type, *null* for reference types, and default value for value types (whatever it is for the type).

Comment: @Habib why making two answers exactly same? :) Not my downvote btw

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy, just after editing I realized he is returning `FirstOrDefault` from `treatment` *(from query)* :) I thought it was a small mistake and fixed it

Comment: This shouldn't be downvoted, it was correct in the earlier form as well and now too.

Comment: I change it back anyway.Sergey is right, he posted the answer with predicate first.

Comment: I can assume it was downvoted because of *returns null* which is not correct if Treatment is a struct. It should be *default value*. PS don't like those who downvote without comments

Answer (score 5):

Use [`Enumerable.FirstOrDefault(Func<T, bool> predicate)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549039%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) extension method, which returns first item from sequence matching predicate, or default value of T (*null* for reference type) if there is no such items:

```
Treatment treatment = treatments.FirstOrDefault(t => t.ID == id);
```

That is almost same as

```
treatments.Where(t => t.ID == id).FirstOrDefault()
// or treatment.FirstOrDefault()
```

But it has a little better performance (theoretically).

---

Thus you have `List<T>` you can also use it's [`Find(Predicate<T> match)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x0b5b5bc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method:

```
Treatment treatment = treatments.Find(t => t.ID == id);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you don't care if there is more than one match or if there are no matches, and therefore you just want the first match if it exists (or null if no matches exist and Treatment is a reference type):

```
return treatments.FirstOrDefault(t => t.ID == id);
```

If you want it to be an error if there are no matches, but you don't care if there is more than one match:

```
return treatments.First(t => t.ID == id);
```

If you want it to be an error if there is more than one match, but you don't care if there are no matches:

```
return treatments.SingleOrDefault(t => t.ID == id);
```

If you want it to be an error if there are no matches or more than one match:

```
return treatments.Single(t => t.ID == id);
```